# How to install forever-monitor module using npm in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, monitor, forever

In my application i want to restart my node js server programmatically.For that i need to install forever-monitor while installing that module using npm im getting error as "No compatible version found: forever-monitor".My node version is v 0.6.17.Can anyone help to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you need Forever to restart your server? Stopping and starting it should be something like two lines of code.

Comment: @SebastianG hi i dont know how to restart the server programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade to 0.8 atleast. forever-monitor requires node 0.8.x. See [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/issues/1).

You can check the node version required for a particular package by looking for `engine` field

```
npm view forever-monitor

{ name: 'forever-monitor',
  description: 'Core forever process monitor',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '1.1.0' },
...
engines: { node: '0.8.x' },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to at least node 0.8? Node.js is now on 0.10.2 so 0.6 is pretty old and many modules are no longer supporting 0.6.

Forever and forever-monitor both work very well in 0.8. The nodejitsu team is working on making forever compatible with 0.10 so that should happen soon.

Also have you looked at https://github.com/substack/fleet? Fleet is an excellent way to manage deployments and running processes.

Answer (score 0):

To restart your server you don't need forever. Just create, close and create the server. A small example:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = startServer();
// ...
server = restartServer(server);
// ...
server = restartServer(server);

function startServer() {
  return http.createServer(server).listen(server.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port " + server.get('port'));
  });
}

function restartServer(server) {
  server.close();
  return startServer();
}
```